# Using C++ unmanaged dll in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to access the functions in a C++ unmanaged dll and I'm struggling to get any results.  Here is what I have far:

```
static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntPtr testIntPtr = aaeonAPIOpen(0);

        var DevID = aaeonWdtGetDevID(testIntPtr);

        Console.WriteLine("DevID: " + DevID.ToString()); //Does not work

        byte pbData1 = 0;
        byte pbData2 = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Before: {0} {1}", pbData1.ToString(), pbData2.ToString());

        aaeon12VData(testIntPtr, &pbData1, &pbData2); //Notice long delay, but doesn't change pbData1 or pbData2

        Console.WriteLine("After: {0} {1}", pbData1.ToString(), pbData2.ToString());
    }


    [DllImport("aonAPI.dll", EntryPoint = "?aaeonWdtGetDevID@@YAGPAX@Z", ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern ushort aaeonWdtGetDevID(IntPtr hInst);
    //C++ Code
    //DLLAPI WORD aaeonWdtGetDevID(HANDLE hInst);

    [DllImport("aonAPI.dll", EntryPoint = "?aaeon12VData@@YAJPAXPAE1@Z", ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern unsafe IntPtr aaeon12VData(IntPtr hInst, byte* pbData, byte* pbData2);
    // C++ code
    //DLLAPI HRESULT aaeon12VData(HANDLE hInst, BYTE* pbData, BYTE* pbData2);

    [DllImport("aonAPI.dll", EntryPoint = "?aaeonAPIOpen@@YAPAXK@Z", ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern IntPtr aaeonAPIOpen(uint reserved);
    // C++ code
    //DLLAPI HANDLE aaeonAPIOpen(DWORD reserved);
```

And here is how the C++ program uses the API for the 12V:

```
while(hInst == NULL)
{
    hInst = aaeonAPIOpen(0);
}

unsigned char temp;
unsigned char temp2;

if(aaeon12VData(hInst,&temp,&temp2) == S_OK)
{
    m_message.Format(_T("%d.%d"),temp2,temp);
}
```

Here is the dumpbin:

```
      3    2 00001380 ?aaeon12VData@@YAJPAXPAE1@Z
      5    4 00001020 ?aaeonAPIOpen@@YAPAXK@Z
     10    9 00001040 ?aaeonWdtGetDevID@@YAGPAX@Z
```

Comment: The currency at SO is up-votes.  You inspire contributors to help you by using them.  They are tax free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you make the following change to call "byref", you will solve your problem:

```
public static extern unsafe IntPtr aaeon12VData(IntPtr hInst, ref byte pbData, byte pbData2);
```

and:

```
aaeon12VData(testIntPtr, ref pbData1, ref pbData2);
```

Comment: Turns out I had an outdated dll so I couldn't connect.  Your ref was helpful after I got past that point.

Answer (score 1):

Your C# code appears to reference mangled-names for entry points.  That strikes me as very suspicious - likely wrong.  Try it without the mangled names (use the pre-mangled names).

Comment: I think you're on it. Also notice the "cdecl" calling convention, that would never work with mangled-names. It would of had to been "fastcall" or "thiscall" I believe. If he changes it to the unmangled names cdecl should work. Oh, and "native code" is a better description than "unmanaged" code, imho. :-)

Comment: I get entry point errors without specifying the mangled names.

Comment: Ok, two more things.  Try removing the "extern" on your C# forward declarations.  Also, are you sure that an IntPtr is the proper representation of a hInst?  If hInst is a handle (such as to a kernel object), then an IntPtr probably is not what you are looking for.